# How to make a running workflow to complete state in sharepoint 2010 Out Of The Box (OOTB)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, content-approval

I have created a demo workflow .

Document uploaded by Author -> Document Published by Any Approver/Admin  - >Approver changes status In Ribbon from In Progress to Approved -> Workflow Initiated by Author -> Approvers click on Document and go to Workflow in the Ribbon -> Approver goes to workflow Information page and approves the Doc

[image]

My workflow status is showing Approved but the workflow is still under "Running Workflows" column .

Can anyone suggest me how to make it to completed workflow OOTB?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the **transition to End of Workflow** i.e as below-

Once you have finished with the approving the document set that item/workflow => **Add  Action** => **Stop Workflow**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Our workflow is OOTB workflow not a custom workflow and dont have permission to use SharePoint designer .

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciated .

Comment: I think you had added some steps after the workflow finished.
Can you please mention the steps here?

Comment: Document Uploaded by Auther -> Document Published by Approver  through Ribbon Publish button ->Approver changes status In Ribbon from In Progress to Approved .->Workflow Initiated by Auther->Approvers click on Document and go to Workflow in the Ribbon -> Approver Goes to workflow Information page and approves the Doc